# Unable store the objects into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to store the objects into Javascript array.

```
var res=[
    {name:'Alex',place:'US',age:20},
    {name:'Jason',place:'Canada',age:25}
  ];

var obj={};
var data=[];

for ( let i in res){
    obj.name=res[i].name;
    obj.place=res[i].place;
    data.push(obj);
 }

console.log(data);
```

My expected output:

```
[ 
  {name:'Alex',place:'US'}.
  {name:'Jason',place:'Canada'} 
]
```

Actual output I got:

```
[ 
  {name:'Jason',place:'Canada'},
  {name:'Jason',place:'Canada' }
]
```

Why I'm getting this type of output?
I'm noobie.Please help me.

Comment: Separately, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for why you probably don't want to use `for ( let i in res){`.

Answer (score 2):

You only have one object in memory with your `var obj={};` - that line runs *once*, and creates *one* object in memory, which you then proceed to mutate on every iteration in the `for` loop, and push to the array. At the end, the array contains 2 references to the same object.

Create the object inside the loop instead:

```
for ( let i in res){
    var obj = {};
    obj.name=res[i].name;
    obj.place=res[i].place;
    data.push(obj);
}
```

You could also consider using `.map` instead:

```js
const res=[
  {name:'Alex',place:'US',age:20},
  {name:'Jason',place:'Canada',age:25}
];
const data = res.map(({ name, place }) => ({ name, place }));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are basically **updating** the same object again and again in your loop. You need to have different objects for each loop. Hence, you need to move `var obj={}` inside the for loop.

```js
var res=[{name:'Alex',place:'US',age:20},{name:'Jason',place:'Canada',age:25}];


var data=[];

for ( let i in res){
    var obj={};
    obj.name=res[i].name;
    obj.place=res[i].place;
    data.push(obj);
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using .map would be much easier

```js
    var res=[
        {name:'Alex',place:'US',age:20},
        {name:'Jason',place:'Canada',age:25}
      ];
    
    var obj={};
    var data = res.map(({ name, place }) => {
      return ({ name, place })
    });
    console.log(data);
```